# Prompt the user for a word then check it for double characters

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check a word for repeated letters. For example, words like "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious," and "emphasis," should not have any double letters in it, but words like "different," "mississippi," and "formatting" should. This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

Comment: [**do not post code in images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Copy and paste them as text

Comment: And after you include the text of the program in your question, also explain exactly what your question is. This is something fundamental that's missing from your question: an actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each character of a string, then compare the next character in the string to the previous.

Example

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::string str = "Mississippi";
  for (int i = str.size(); i > 0; i--)
      if (str[i] == str[i-1])
          std::cout << "- " << str[i] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not enough that the duplicate characters exist at all, they need to be sequential. Look at the examples the OP provided. Your code doesn't handle this requirement. You don't need a vector to implement this, just a simple loop that checks if the current character matches the last character seen

Comment: @RemyLebeau I changed it.

Comment: note your code has *undefined behavior* prior to C++11 when `i` reaches `length()-1`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, I changed that too. Thanks.

Comment: your code still has *undefined behavior* prior to C++11. You keep indexing the string out of bounds, but C++11 has a rule that allows special consideration for accessing a null terminator when the index is the same as the `size()`, previous versions did not have that rule. Not everyone uses C++11 or later yet

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but your approach is using the wrong data type for the input, and it is outputting the result incorrectly.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream> // for cout and cin
#include <string>   // for string commands
using namespace std;

bool hasDoubleChars(const string &str) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == str[i-1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    string str;

    cout << "Welcome to the DoubleChecker(TM) word checker" << endl;
    cout << "=============================================" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a word to check: " << endl;
    cin >> str;

    if (hasDoubleChars(str)) {
        cout << "There are double characters in the word " << str << ".";
    } else {
        cout << "There are no double characters in the word " << str << ".";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/uiDUgi)

Comment: I see what you did there. Thank You!